# Populating Array of Pointers in Function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, inheritance, arduino

I have a class with an array of pointers that gets dynamically allocated in the constructor.  This class also has a function to populate the array.

```
HolderClass::HolderClass(int number)
{
  arrayOfPointers = new ItemClass*[number];
}

HolderClass::addItem(int number, ItemClass item)
{
  arrayofPointers[number] = &item;
}
```

Even though this would compile is my understanding correct in that I would actually be populating the array with dangling pointers since the lifetime of the item variable is only for the duration of the addItem function?

What would be the correct way of populating the arrayOfPointers with pointers to the passed in items?  The one complexity here is that there will be child classes of ItemClass that will get passed to the addItem function so I don't believe default copy constructors could be used.

EDIT: This code is for an Arduino so I'm fairly limited in what can and can't be done.  This also means that I would like to keep things simply for users of this class (since there are lots of Arduino newbies) and not require them to pass in a pointer to the addItem function (which would require them to manage the life of the passed in ItemClass object).

Answer (score 0):

> What would be the correct way of populating the arrayOfPointers with pointers to the passed in items?

Firstly, don't use raw `new` and `delete`. Use containers and smart pointers.

```
struct HolderClass
{
    std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<ItemClass>[]> arrayOfPointers;
    // ...
};

HolderClass::HolderClass(int number)
{
     arrayOfPointers = std::make_unique<std::unique_ptr<ItemClass>[]>(number);
}
```

Then, pass a pointer to `addItem` instead of a value to avoid object slicing and lifetime issues:

```
HolderClass::addItem(int number, std::unique_ptr<ItemClass> item)
{
    arrayofPointers[number] = std::move(item);
}
```

Comment: "Use containers and smart pointers." Why not using `std::vector` then?

Comment: By default vector is also not available on an Arduino.  You can get access to it via a third party library but I'd prefer to not go that route if I don't have to to keep the code size down.

Comment: To more closely match the OP's design.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing from std is normally available on the Arduino so I need a more basic solution.